# How do I create a Windows 7 USB installer with preinstalled software?

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, images

I was wondering if it was possible to make a bootlable image of a Windows 7 Pro OEM Installation CD that I have and put it on an USB stick for faster/easier installation. I am asking because we have a couple of PC´s where I´d have to install the OS using the same key (MAK).

Also is it possible to kind of populate that image with software that would have to be installed anyways on all machines (like Chrome, Outlook, etc)?

It would be really helpful to just install a Windows 7 image with customized software already installed. I would just make an image of an OS and use that, but the hardware of the machines differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defiantly can with WAIK. Take a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee530017) at how to set up an image and [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/) to boot off a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [WAIK](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Windows_Automated_Installation_Kit).

Comment: Can you give a brief overview of what WAIK is and how it works?

Comment: To what degree does the link I provided not do that?

Comment: If it becomes a dead link then it does nothing at all.

Comment: @Joe Taylor It would not be legal for me to attribute my answer as my own if I were to copy it from Wikipedia, and neither would it be right to. If you are suggesting that the demise of Wikipedia is imminent, then that's your prerogative. Otherwise, see https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Wikipedia:NOTABILITY . Notability is not temporary, and by all standards WAIK is a notable subject matter.

Comment: You simply say you've referenced the text. I'm not suggesting Wikipedia is close to demise but it should never be taken for granted that things are permanent. Best practice would be to include a brief synopsis and to also link to Wikipedia for a full explanation.